# Spring Repository method for first()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

In Grails, I can say `Foo.first()`. In Spring, I have repositories extending `PagingAndSortingRepository` and I've created a service method called `getFirst()` that does the following:

```
public Foo getFirst() {
  return fooRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort("ASC", "id"))).getContent().get(0);
}
```

Is this the best way or is there a convenience method I'm just missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a query method on the repository interface like this:

```
Foo findFirstByOrderByIdAsc();
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result